# Adding a nature on a custom project within an Eclipse plugin fails

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm developping a plugin to implement a custom project kind with custom nature and builder. Within a new wizard, I execute the following code to create the project:

```
IProject newProject = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
                                .getProject(projectName);
IProjectDescription desc = newProject.getWorkspace()
                .newProjectDescription(newProject.getName());
desc.setLocationURI(projectLocation);
try {
    newProject.create(desc, null);
    if (!newProject.isOpen()) {
        newProject.open(null);
    }
} catch (CoreException e) { (...) }
```

Now the project is created, I try to add the nature with the following code:

```
if (!project.hasNature(MyNature.NATURE_ID)) {
    IProjectDescription description = project.getDescription();
    String[] prevNatures = description.getNatureIds();
    String[] newNatures = new String[prevNatures.length + 1];
    System.arraycopy(prevNatures, 0, newNatures, 0, prevNatures.length);
    newNatures[prevNatures.length] = MyNature.NATURE_ID;
    description.setNatureIds(newNatures);
    IProgressMonitor monitor = new NullProgressMonitor();
    project.setDescription(description, monitor);
}
```

Here is the content of my plugin.xml file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Eclipse
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.myapp.eclipse;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.myapp.eclipse.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: MyApp
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.6.1",
 org.eclipse.ui.ide;bundle-version="3.6.2"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.7
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Export-Package: com.myapp.eclipse,
 com.myapp.eclipse.builder,
 com.myapp.eclipse.nature,
 com.myapp.eclipse.saving
```

All these codes partially work since the project is actually created but there is no .project file within it. I can't see any error.

What did I do wrong and how can I debug the problem?

Thanks for your help.
Thierry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be because you are setting the project location in the project description. Instead of

```java
desc.setLocationURI(projectLocation);
```

call

```java
desc.setLocation(null);
```

The location in the description should only be set if it is not the default.